# Is the any.description() function a replacement for the description property of any.default()

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm upgrading from `hapi-browser` to `@hapi/joi` and `any.default([value, [description]])` has been replaced with `any.default([value])`.

I could not really find any information on what the description property is or does and so I don't know if I should add the `any.description(desc)` function to replace the description property's function or if I should just leave it out.